# How to run multiple bash scripts from python master script in parallel?

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I have a series of time consuming independent bash scripts to be run in parallel on 7 CPU cores from python master script. I tried to implement this using multiprocessing.Pool.map() function iterating over numbers from xrange(1, 300) sequence, where every number is used to define the name of a directory containing bash script to be executed. The issue is that the following script spawns 7 processes for bash script runs and finishes right after they are completed.

```
import multiprocessing
import os
a= os.getcwd() #gets current path
def run(x):
            b = a + '/' + 'dir%r' % (x) # appends the name of targeted folder to path
            os.chdir(b) #switches to the targeted directory
            os.system('chmod +x run.sh')
            os.system('./run.sh') # runs the time consuming script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = 7
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(procs)
    p.map(run, xrange(1, 300))
    print "====DONE===="
```

I expect other 292 shell scripts to be run as well, so what fix or alternative implementation could help me?
Thank you!